# SQL aggregating running count of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am relatively new to SQL so apologies for any stupid questions, but I can't even get close on this.

I have a data set of customer orders which consists of **Cust_ID** and **Date**. I want to return a query that has all the customer orders adding two fields, "Date of first order" and "order count"

```
Cust_ID    Date        FirstOrder     orderCount
5001       04/10/13    04/10/13       1
5001       11/10/13    04/10/13       2
5002       11/10/13    11/10/13       1
5001       17/10/13    04/10/13       3
5001       24/10/13    04/10/13       4
5002       24/10/13    11/10/13       2
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you write any code?

Comment: I did but didn't make any progress so I didn't post anything. Your solution below was perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT foo.Cust_ID
     , foo.`Date`
     , MIN(p.`Date`) AS FirstOrder
     , COUNT(*) AS orderCount
FROM foo
JOIN foo AS p
  ON p.Cust_id = foo.Cust_id
    AND p.`Date` <= foo.`Date`
GROUP BY foo.Cust_ID, foo.`Date`
ORDER BY foo.`Date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

Source data you have:

```
Cust_ID    Date
5001       04/10/13   
5001       11/10/13   
5002       11/10/13   
5001       17/10/13  
5001       24/10/13    
5002       24/10/13
```

Result dataset you expect:

```
Cust_ID    Date        FirstOrder     OrderNumber
5001       04/10/13    04/10/13       1
5001       11/10/13    04/10/13       2
5002       11/10/13    11/10/13       1
5001       17/10/13    04/10/13       3
5001       24/10/13    04/10/13       4
5002       24/10/13    11/10/13       2
```

Then query should be (if using AF):

```
SELECT Cust_ID, Date,
       MIN(Date) over ( partition by Cust_ID ) as FirstOrder,
       RowNumber() over ( partition by Cust_ID order by Date asc ) as OrderNumber
FROM   Orders
```

Excluding AF, using only standart SQL:

```
SELECT S.Cust_ID, S.Date, MIN(J.Date) as FirstDate, Count(S.Cust_id)
FROM Orders S
INNER JOIN Orders J
ON S.Cust_ID = J.Cust_ID and S.Date >= J.Date
GROUP BY S.Cust_id, S.Date
```

Comment: The question needs a MySQL answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT tab.Cust_ID, tab.Date, x.FirstOrder, x.orderCount
FROM tab INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Cust_ID, MIN(Date) AS FirstOrder,
        COUNT(*) AS orderCount
    FROM tab
    GROUP BY CustID
) x ON tab.Cust_ID = x.Cust_ID
```

**The inner query** selects `FirstOrder` and `orderCount` for each customer and finally joined with for each orders.

### updated

with `user variables` you can keep track of sequence of order count of Cust_ID

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT tab.Cust_ID, tab.Date AS Date, x.FirstOrder, x.orderCount,
        IF(@prev_cust_id = tab.Cust_ID, @cnt := @cnt + 1, @cnt := 1)
    FROM tab INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Cust_ID, MIN(Date) AS FirstOrder,
            COUNT(*) AS orderCount
        FROM tab
        GROUP BY CustID
    ) x ON tab.Cust_ID = x.Cust_ID,
    (SELECT @prev_cust_id := 0, @cnt := 1) y
    ORDER BY tab.Cust_ID
) x
ORDER BY Date;
```

Comment: That works except it gives total count for each record as opposed to running total

Comment: @user3169268 Aha. I misunderstood your question during working. wait a minute please.

Comment: @user3169268 I've updated. but not tested on your data. When preceding SQL does not work for you, please give us some sample data on sqlFiddle.